# how to add an entity in model that is already live

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app with core date integrated. I have currently 2 entities defined and the app is already live in the app store

In my next release I want to add one more entity in the future version but when I run the app in the simulator I get the following error

The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store.

What should I do if i want to add another entity to my model.

Should I create another model object?

NOTE: I don't want to lose the date stored in the existing model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the Persistent Store options for automatic migration:

Change your persistentStoreCoordinator creation to this (replace YOURDB):

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

  if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator;
  }

  NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"YOURDB.sqlite"]];

  // handle db upgrade
  NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

  NSError *error = nil;
  persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel: [self managedObjectModel]];
  if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:options error:&error]) {
    // Handle error
  }

  return persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

1. Version your Data Model and Edit the new file

   ```
    - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

        if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
              return managedObjectModel;
            }



          NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YOURRESOURCENAME" ofType:@"momd"];
       NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
                 managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];


             return managedObjectModel;
           }
   ```

Comment: are you providing two solutions, or two steps to the same solution. Can I set these options even if I had not set them in the previous version of my app?

Comment: no its one solution ,its about creating model version and coredata will migrate automatically. NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new version of your model and do a migration. (probably lightweight by the sounds of it). Have a look at this link
[Apple Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/Introduction.html)